# CoreGraphics zigzag and hash line between 2 CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm building an iOS project using Swift.
How do I draw a *zig-zag* path using *CoreGraphics* ? How do I calculate all the intermediary points?

I also need to draw a *hash line*? Is this possible to create with *CoreGraphics* ?

As an example of what I try to achieve:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There are various ways to do this - including stroking a `UIBezierPath` and / or using a `CAReplicatorLayer`. What have you accomplished so far? Can you draw a single line?

Comment: @DonMag I am able to draw lines and other objects. I also found the algorithm for how to calculate the lines for the arrow, based on the start and end point. I am looking for a way to create or a custom path (between to points) or the algorithm to identify the points for the zigzag.

Comment: OK - but a bit more info is needed. Do you want a predetermined "step size" - where you need to calculate the number of steps? Or, do you want a predetermined number of steps - where you need to calculate the "step size"?

Comment: step size will always be the same (20), the idea is that first the user adds the zigzag (one touch, touchPoint is the start point and the end point is 200 to the left), but when is moving one end of the zigzag line will redraw based on the start and end point (considering that those 2 points can be anywhere in the canvas).  I have in place how I'm moving the ends of the line, all I need to find out how to calculate that intermediary points for the zigzag.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea would be:

- get the width: pt2.x - pt1.x
- get the height: pt2.y - pt1.y
- step-width is 20, so divide width by 20 to get number of steps
- step-height will be height / number of steps
- create a `UIBezierPath`
- loop through number of steps, incrementing the x and y values for `.lineTo(pt)`

Here's an example - note that it has no error handling, and will need additional logic if `pt2` is **not** to the right and lower than `pt1`:

```
class SampleCGView: UIView {
    
    var pt1: CGPoint = .zero
    var pt2: CGPoint = .zero
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // green line to show pt1 to pt2
        let linePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: pt1)
        linePath.addLine(to: pt2)
        UIColor.green.setStroke()
        linePath.stroke()
        
        let zigzagPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        let numSteps: CGFloat = (pt2.x - pt1.x) / 20.0
        // step width is 20
        let xInc: CGFloat = 20
        // step height is based on line angle
        let yInc: CGFloat = (pt2.y - pt1.y) / numSteps
        var pt: CGPoint = pt1
        zigzagPath.move(to: pt)
        for _ in 1...Int(numSteps) {
            zigzagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pt.x + xInc * 0.75, y: pt.y - yInc * 0.25))
            zigzagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pt.x + xInc, y: pt.y + yInc))
            pt.x += xInc
            pt.y += yInc
        }
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        zigzagPath.stroke()
        
    }
    
}
```

Sample view controller to demo:

```
class SampleDrawViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let v = SampleCGView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(v)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -80.0),
        ])
        
        // set start and end points for the zigzag line
        v.pt1 = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)
        v.pt2 = CGPoint(x: 260, y: 160)
        
    }
}
```

Result (the green line is drawn only to make `pt1` and `pt2` locations clear):

[image]